# Access repeated item inside ng-repeated directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a custom directive in AngularJS that I need to be repeated a couple of times. Currently, my page looks like this:

```
<div my-item ng-repeat="item in items" />
```

And my directive looks like this:

```
module.directive('myItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: { item: '&' },
        template: '<div id="item{{$index}}"></div>',
        link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
            element.append('<div>' + $scope.item.name + '</div>');
        }
    };
});
```

However, inside the linking function, `$scope.item.name` yields undefined. I'm wondering if there is any way I could access the repeated item inside my directive.

If not, what would be my alternatives? Move the `ng-repeat` inside the directive, maybe?

P.S. I know that you should (generally speaking) not do DOM manipulation this way, but since I might have ~2000 items that would result in 6000 bindings, and I'm afraid that would lead to severe performance issues.

Comment: I have created a sample for you http://plnkr.co/edit/l5r6zIc7ncT1XldRuB98?p=preview

Comment: Well, that is actually an answer. Works flawlessly. Feel free to move it to an answer instead, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass item as attribute to directive created a sample directive 
http://plnkr.co/edit/l5r6zIc7ncT1XldRuB98?p=preview